# ajax postback method for refreshing dropdown list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Scoop...

I have a drop down list that might not display a particular option you're looking for. I added a button with pop up modal to type in a field you want to add to the drop down list. It functions perfectly, but I need to add an ajax postback method to refresh the list after the user hits enter. I don't want to refresh the whole page, just the list. any help?

**Controller**:

```
        public ActionResult AddLeadSource()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddLeadSource(string name)
    {
        LeadSource ls = new LeadSource();
        ls.Name = name;
        db.LeadSources.Add(ls);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$("#AddNew").change(function () {
    var name = $("#Name").val();
    // var order = $("#DisplayOrder").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Admin/LeadSource/AddLeadSource',
        data: { name: name },
        success: function (response) {
            //alert("Success " + response.success);
            $('#FollowUpNotes').kendoWindow('destroy');
            // Refresh the DropDown <-- Heres where I need some help!


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the name of the DropDown list? you want to refresh or reset? since i can't see any data returned from ajax request that you can use to refresh your dropdown.

Comment: You would need to either include all the values of dropdown in the response of AddLeadSource and then replace the list with these or just add the new one in success

Answer (score 2):

In your success function of your Ajax call add this:

```
$("IdOfDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
```

In this way your dropdownlist will call the read function and reload all data. I assumed that your dropdownlist is binding throught read call.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking at jQuery UI's autocomplete widget.  That said,

```
 $('#YourDropDownID option').remove(); //this will remove all option elements inside the <select id="YourDropDownID">
```

Then you just need to build new ones based on the response data,

```
        for (var o in data) {
            if (data[o].Value != undefined) {
                $('#YourDropDownID').append('<option value="' + data[o].Value + '">' + ("" + data[o].Display) + '</option>');
            }
        }
```

I do this inside the `.done()` callback of my AJAX:

```
    .done(function (data) {
        //above code
    }
```

Depending on the nature of the data you are sending back you may need to loop through it differently.  Mine is an array of objects with a Value and Display properties (in my case, account numbers and account names).

```
//server side controller
    var query = @"
    Select
        SubString([mn_no], 0, 6) As Value,
        RTRIM([acct_desc]) As Display
    From [some_table]";
            return con.Query(query, new { AccountNumber = accounts.Select(x =>
            {
                return new { Value = x.Value, Display = x.Display };
            });
```